# Disable Marks Column from Sublime Text 2 Gutter

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to disable the marks column in the gutter on the left side of Sublime Text 2?

I was able to disable the `fold_buttons` using the following setting in the settings file:

```
"fold_buttons": false
```

In case it isn't clear, I'm talking about the whitespace reserved for the mark (dot) shown below:

[image: mark in gutter]

Comment: could you post a pic? I'm not sure what you're talking about...

Comment: Sure thing. I've posted one.

Answer (score 1):

Find "Settings - User" from Sublime Text 2 menus (its location depending on the platform). When you click it, it will open a new, empty or almost empty file. Here is a sample portion of it:

```
{
    "auto_complete": true,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
    "gutter": true
}
```

The setting you are asking for is the "gutter". Make it false and you will achieve what you asked for.

Things to note:

- The curly braces at the beginning and end are important.
- Each setting has a comma after it. Except the last one.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with using JSON notation for the settings. Unfortunately, your solution of setting `"gutter": false` isn't what I'm looking for. That removes the line numbers along with the marks column and I want to keep the line numbers.